# Removing mysql table lock

Tags: mysql

Trying to run the following on mysql server 5.5:

```
DELETE FROM `territories` WHERE `territories`.`id` = 2012603
```

I eventually get:

```
Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: DELETE FROM `territories` WHERE `territories`.`id` = 2012603
```

I see this is often caused by a lock on the table, but when I try:

```
show open tables;
```

That table (territories) is not locked - 0 for In_use, 0 for Name_locked.

I've tried killing all the various mysql processes, but without success.  That delete query won't run.  I've tried rebooting the server, restarting mysql, upgrading mysql.  All without success.

What am I missing here?

Comment: any triggers on that table that might be interfering?

Comment: I'm not familiar with triggers...I haven't set any up on the table.